# Please help me with this ceiling fan wiring

Tags: ceiling-fan

I'm having a little trouble with wiring my ceiling fan. According to the instruction, black and blue from the mounting plate goes to black wire from the outlet box. White wire goes to the white one from outlet box. But the ground copper wire is not coming out (pic) for wiring. I tried to connect the two ground wires of the bracket and the mounting plate only but it didn't work (both the light and the fan). The model I'm using is LED Clarkston II 44 inch ceiling fan (SW18030). Thank you.

[image: mounting plate]

[image: outlet box]

[image: mounting bracket]

Comment: Ground wire is only for your safety.  The circuit works if used or not.  If the fan/light does not work, then there is a bad connection somewhere or the fan/light is defective.  You did turn the breaker back on and the switch is on?

Comment: yes, I have everything on but it still doesn't work. I presume the switch box is defective but it's less likely. Is there any way to check that? Otherwise, I'd have to return the fan.

Comment: The best way is to use a multi-meter and see/check you have 120v between the white and black wires(with switch on), and 0v with switch off.  This checks the switch also.  Also re check the connections between the fan and black/white wires, a bad/loose connection there will also cause no power.

Comment: This isn't replacing a light fixture that was on a switch leg, is it?  That pancake box looks kinda shallow.

Comment: Hello Huesmann, all I did was take the old fan out and this is what's there. I didn't touch or fix the pancake box whatsoever.

Comment: Hello crisp659, my old ceiling fan worked just fine before I took it out (except for the light). But sure I'll try and check the connection.

Comment: Have you pulled the chains on the fan itself (in addition to operating the wall switch and breaker). I have forgotten this obvious step more times than I care to admit when installing these, left wondering why it isn't working.

Comment: I did pull the chain multiple times. None worked.